# Plot with Rmarkdown in html documen

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I have the following code from my file "prueba.R":

```
variables<-c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Width")
#+ results='asis',fig.height = 3, fig.width = 3

for (v in variables) {
  cat("## Variable  \n")
  boxplot(iris[,v],size=1)
  cat("  \n")
}
```

When I render it into a html document:

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("prueba.R","html_document")
```

I have this output:

[image]

As you can see, the format of the second "Variable" gets lots. How can I prevent it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing spaces from `cat` seems to solve it.

```
variables<-c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Width")
#+ results='asis',fig.height = 3, fig.width = 3

for (v in variables) {
  cat("## Variable  \n")
  boxplot(iris[,v],size=1)
  cat("\n\n")
}
```

In another file -

```
library(rmarkdown)
render("preuba.R","html_document")
```

[image]